# Architecturing a React application

Tags: reactjs

I have a question regarding the architecture of an React application.

The application consists from main widget and a few other child widgets. Each of them may have other child widgets too. The widgets don't know what do they do, neither how many they are (they are provided by the user).

Here is an example:

In the picture below there are initially two widgets, each of them have several child widgets.

1. On step #1 the two widgets are visible and they have a few child widgets too.
2. On step #2 the user clicked somewhere on the page. Because of that, another child widget appeared in the first widget.
3. On step #3, user clicked in some of the child widgets in widget 2. In this case, only this widget should appear. The others in widget 2 should disappear.
4. On step #4 clicking on a child widget in widget 2 should cause that widget 1 will disappear entirely.

The question is - how do we manage this situation? I imagine clicking on child widget or somewhere on the page should notify the root so it will add a new widget or skip rendering of the other ones. However, I can't really imagine what to put in the state and how exactly to achieve this.

[image: Example]

Comment: There are lots of ways to accomplish this ... but it's not clear what you need help with? It seems like you need a global store of some sort that has a state-machine that controls visibility? You could use events, dispatcher, flux, a store, etc.

Comment: Maybe this question was too broad...
I have troubles to imagine how to propagate the changes from a widget deep down in the hierarchy to the root.

For example:

When the child on step #4 requires that only it should be shown, it requests something like "exclusive" state. This means we have to store somehow information that its direct parents should be shown only and none of its siblings.

This is what I'm working on. I have alternatives - from separate tree structure to calling function on the parent and so on. But maybe this is too specific for my app and no general help could be provided.

Comment: I've seen a lot of code use callbacks.  But, using. Flux pattern might work as well.

Comment: I thought about Flux, and actually I drew a possible solution on the whiteboard. It does not fully fit however - there are no stores in the sense of Flux. The UI depends primary on user actions, which don't not strictly add/remove/modify data. Maybe I will still go to Flux like pattern, but more simplified.

Answer (score 0):

So, here is how we did it in the end of the ends:

We invented so called "exclusive mode" of an widget. The parent component passes a callback function via properties. Then, a child widget may request to be rendered in "exclusive mode".
When rendering in exclusive more is being requested, the parent renders only those widget, which key matches with the key of the widget, requested exclusive access.
In this way, only one Toolbar may be rendered or only some button may be rendered in given Toolbar.